# Find if multiple columns contain a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a df with columns ID, Value, A,B,C. I want to check if a string, say "Type AB", is in any row of the columns A, B, C. If its present, I want to mark that it "Present" for that row in the new column "TypeAB_present". How do I achieve this in python?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `np.where` with `any`

```
df['TypeAB _present'] = np.where(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].eq('Type AB').any(axis = 1 ), 'Present', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using pandas and you're looking for the exact 'Type AB' tag from any of the columns.

```
df['TypeAB_present'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda row: 'Present' if 'Type AB' in row.values else '', axis=1)
```

Comment: How do I specify to only look in column A,B, and C

Comment: @Fazli see update, I would however recommend the other answer, it is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
                'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB02', 'AB01', 'AB01'],
                'Values': [57, 98, 87, 69, 98],
                'A': ['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type B', 'Type B', 'Type AB'],
                'B': [None, 'Type AB', None, 'Type A', None]
        }
)

df.loc[(df[['A', 'B']] == 'Type AB').any(axis=1), 'C'] = 'Present'
df
```

Out

```
     ID  Values        A        B        C
0  AB01      57   Type A     None      NaN
1  AB02      98   Type B  Type AB  Present
2  AB02      87   Type B     None      NaN
3  AB01      69   Type B   Type A      NaN
4  AB01      98  Type AB     None  Present
```

If your check is slightly more complicated than exact equality match, you can create a more robust mask for indexing. Here I'm checking to see if any of the strings in columns A or B contain the substring 'AB':

```
match_mask = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('AB')).any(axis=1)
df.loc[match_mask, 'C'] = 'Present'
```